# Consuming generated google endpoint api jar in android client

Tags: android, rx-java, google-cloud-endpoints, retrofit2, rx-android

I have a server backend endpoint written in java and have successfully implemented the generated client code in iOS but trying to make sense of how I can implement or consume the generated code in the android studio for the backend endpoint? I see google documentation for generating [client for android](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/generate-client-libraries-android) and on same page shows step no.5 where it says add the generated jar to the android studio to consume [endpoints from android](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/calling-from-android)  , but how you consume the api? i see examples from google where it shows only google endpoint written in android and consumed in android also, where is the documentation or sample to follow consuming a server endpoint generated code from server project to  client in android.

I have seen lots of threads but i don't seem to find any single step by step documentation where you can follow it or implement it.

Comment: do you want to integrate .jar file to your project ?

Comment: yes and generated code from endpoints, i imported jar but there is lack of information how to consume efficiently endpoint server generated code in android app.

Comment: Kindly share your code @nsgulliver

Comment: what you mean share code? there is no code on client android yet, server side is endpoint written in java, which is a working app with ios client, read the question again if you don't understand